# How to embed java into C#

Tags: c#, java, integration, embed, behavior

Could you tell me, please, how can I embed java module/source code into C# application? For example i have some logic that written on java and this logic uses some third party libraries which can be found only on java platform. And i have main host logic that written on C#. It will be very cool, if i'll be able to register callbacks from java into C#.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html) ?

> IKVM.NET is useful for several different software development scenarios. Here is a sampling of some of the possibilities.
>
> - Drop-in JVM
> - Use Java libraries in your .NET applications
> - Develop .NET applications in Java