# embed java applet into C# desktop application

Tags: c#, java, applet

I have created a website and this website uses the third party java applet to do some tasks.
Now i need to convert the website into the desktop(windows) application. I believe i can convert the web pages into forms but what about the java applets?

Is it possible to embed java applet into the C# desktop application? Any direction to go? These applets are third party, i dont have any source code for it.

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question&answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103979/how-to-embed-java-into-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into Java Native Interface API and [Using the Java Native Interface in C#](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245622/Using-the-Java-Native-Interface-in-Csharp&ei=l67FUPWHF4ezhAfa0IGQDw&usg=AFQjCNE5wWTJ20s-b-rNFeSXehTTzy4Sdw)